# "MessageBodyWriter not found" when returning List<Long> with the Response-object in JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, weblogic, response

I am currently trying to create a rest-webservice which returns an object of the type *List< Long>*. The service is annotated with *@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)*.

I don't have any problems with the other services in this project.

If I write the code as following:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
            list.add(100L);
            list.add(200L);
            list.add(300L);

return Response.ok(list)
               .build();
```

Then I get the following message in the log:

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.
```

If I instead write it as following (same as I did for another service in the project, but where it is a List of pojo objects):

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
            list.add(100L);
            list.add(200L);
            list.add(300L);

GenericEntity<List<Long>> genericEntity = new GenericEntity<List<Long>>(list){};

return Response.ok(genericEntity)
               .build();
```

Then I get the following message instead:

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<java.lang.Long>.
```

After googling I found the following suggestion to convert the List to an array as seen below, but this didn't work either.

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
            list.add(100L);
            list.add(200L);
            list.add(300L);

            return Response.ok(list.toArray()).build();
```

Then I get:

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class [Ljava.lang.Object;, genericType=class [Ljava.lang.Object;.
```

We are using jackson-core version 2.3.2 and the jax-rs implementation is Jersey which is included with Weblogic 12c.

Is there any good solution for this (without using any other libraries)?

Comment: If you're using JAX-RS and wish to return the results as a `List<Long>`, I believe you just return the `List<Long>` itself, not wrapped in a `Response`. JAX-RS will take care of marshalling it into the requested type.

Comment: Yes, that is true. but I also want to return a header in the response message. If there is a problem on the server side I am instead returning an error message with the corresponding http status code.

Comment: Then you would just throw a `WebApplicationException` constructed with the appropriate error code (using the status code constants defined by `Response.Status`). Let JAX-RS do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Seems I have learnt something new today (WebApplicationException). But I still need to be able to add headers to the response, both the correct and the error response.

Comment: Which JAX-RS framework are you using?

Comment: It is Jersey which is included in Weblogic 12c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While returning a List< Long> in a Response object doesn't work for me I have managed to come around it by embedding the list in a new class.

The new class looks as following:

```
public class LongArrayList {

    private List<Long> list;

    public LongArrayList() {

    }

    public LongArrayList(List<Long> list) {
        this.setList(list);
    }

    public List<Long> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Long> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

I then return this list as following:

```
return Response.ok(new LongArrayList(theOldLongList))
               .build();
```

Unfortunatelly this returns a little bigger json than I would want:

```
{"list":[5,12,29,30]}
```

If anybody finds a better solution I will accept it as an answer for this question instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you are producing json type data, Json related jar is required for parsing Object in to json form.

Add Jackson jar to your pom.xml if it is Maven project.

add this dependency..

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Or

download the jar and add it to class path.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have updated the question with the version of Jackson we are using.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which JAX-RS framework you're playing with, but according to [Apache CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-Jackson) for instance, if you want to use Jackson as JSON Provider, you need this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then register one of the Jackson Providers on your JAX-RS service, I guess the one for POJOs in your case, not the one for JAXB beans (WARNING: the package name in CXF documentation is for Jackson 1.x, I replaced with the one for Jackson 2.x):

```
<jaxrs:providers>
   <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
</jaxrs:providers>
```

For Jersey, it would be a [different dependency](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson).

Comment: Thank for your answer! Have now added which frameworks I am using. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't seem to help. I don't think this is the problem as Jackson seems to work for all the other cases.

Comment: Again, which JAX-RS framework are you using? (asked already in previous comments) If you want better answers, that would help checking that it works in your case. Although it's the same JAX-RS standard, there are differences in implementations.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear in the question. It is Jersey which is included in Weblogic 12c. I will update the question with this information.

Comment: OK, I'm afraid I am not used to Jersey / Weblogic environment :-( so maybe Jersey-savvy people have a better answer.